# why does Physical Web need location?

Tags: android, google-chrome, bluetooth, location

To see Physical Web URLs, you need to turn on data (wifi or mobile data), Bluetooth and Location. ([source](https://google.github.io/physical-web/try-physical-web))

Why does it need location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help provide a bit more info (I work on the project) The local scanning and even the information sent to the Google servers, does not look at the users location. The reason this is asked for is just that the website itself can know your location. It's all about the user being aware that this is possible. Users need to know that their location *may* be inferred just by visiting that website.

Answer (score 0):

Well from your Question I came up with an analogy hope it would help you to find your answer.
As you were asking that why does it need location
I think as Physical web itself describes as "an open approach to enable quick and seamless interactions with physical objects and locations." it clearly says that to communicate with nearby objects you must have your location to be identified to that object. It might be an idea to use this location and the location of other object to see that how far are they from each other.

for your reference have a look at below link hope it might help you find your solution:
https://bkon.com/resources/physical-web/